# Задовольняє рівняння чи рівнянню?

Tags: керування-відмінками

У варазах на штиб *задовольняє умові/умову* чи *задовольняє нерівності/нерівність*, чи *задовольняє властивості/властивість*, який відмінок уживати доречніше - знахідний чи давальний?

Я переглянув як це було зроблене в перекладі 3-го видання [Вступу до алгоритмів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B2) і виявив, що знахідний відмінок кількісно переважає в кілька разів.

Наприклад,

- умову/умові - 12/5
- властивість/властивості - 11/1
- властивості/властивостям - 2/0
- вимоги/вимогам - 1/0
- нерівність/нерівності - 18/3

Але тут треба розуміти, що перекладали кілька людей і, можливо, обидва варіанти правильні і просто так сталось, що прихильники варіанту зі знахідним відмінком мали більше траплянь цього звороту.

Comment: Це запитання пов'язане з іншим запитанням на цьому ресурсі https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/Задовольняє-чи-задовільняє-як-правильно/7297?noredirect=1#comment12849_7297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словник Кочерги і Мейнаровича подає:

> - **to meet [satisfy] the conditions** задовольня́ти умо́ви;
> - **to meet the demand** задовольня́ти ви́могу
> - задовольня́ти//задовольни́ти (a condition/requirement – умову/вимогу)
> - **to meet the need** задовольня́ти//задовольни́ти потре́бу
> - **obey 1.** задовольня́ти//задовольни́ти (умови тощо)
> - **to meet the requirements** задовольня́ти потре́би [вимо́ги], відповіда́ти потре́бам [вимо́гам]
>   <sub>Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І англійсько-українська 2010 (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович)</sub>

Отже, треба віддавати перевагу знахідному відмінку.

Comment: Та хоча б надали приклади вжитку, які в Інтеренті є.