# Задовольняє чи задовільняє, як правильно?

Tags: вживання-слів, орфографія, морфологія

Це запитання дотичне до запитання іншого учасника цього ресурсу ["Задовольняє рівняння чи рівнянню?"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/7293/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%94-%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8E) і покликане розширити розуміння користувачів **коли**, **за яких умов** та **як правильно** слід вживати слова **задовольняє** і **задовільняє** при творенні речення. Чи мають право на існування в українській мові обидві словоформи, чи виключно одна?

Чи, можливо, відбувається [чергування голосних **о** - **і**](https://www.dilovamova.com/index.php?page=4&dmua=7&tdmua=%D7%E5%F0%E3%F3%E2%E0%ED%ED%FF-%E3%EE%EB%EE%F1%ED%E8%F5-%E7%E2%F3%EA%B3%E2)? Якщо так, то відповідно до якого з правил Українського правопису? Цікавить всебічний аналіз з наведенням прикладів реального вжитку і можливістю перевірки.

Пошукова система Google надає такі кількісні результати:

```
"задовольняє" - 1 580 000
"задовільняє" - 72 900     
"задовольняти" - 601 000     
"задовільняти" - 31 700
```

І хоча написання слова через **"о"** можна зустріти в десятки разів частіше, кількість випадків написання через **"і"** настільки значна, що явище не можна ігнорувати. Приклади різного написання можна зустріти на багатьох офіційних державних і освітніх ресурсах, при чому не зрідка в межах одного документу. На підтвердження актуальності проблеми наведу яскравий приклад, коли обидві форми слова стоять поруч в межах одного речення.

[**Друга аксіома зліченності**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96):

[image]

> **Академічний тлумачний словник надає такі визначення:**
>
> **[ЗАДОВОЛЬНЯТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zadovoljnjaty)**, яю, яєш, недок.,
>
> 1. Виконувати чиї-небудь вимоги, бажання, претензії і т. ін.
> 2. Викликати у кого-небудь почуття задоволення чимось.
> 3. Бути, виявлятися відповідним до чиїх-небудь вимог, сподівань.
>
> **ЗАДОВІ́ЛЬНИЙ**, а, е. Який задовольняє визначені, потрібні і т. ін. вимоги, умови; прийнятний, достатній.

Answer (score 4):

Сучасний академічний словник містить обидва варіанти:

> [ЗАДОВІЛЬНЯ́ТИ](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=217310&page=962) див. задовольня́ти.
>
> ---
>
> [ЗАДОВІЛЬНИ́ТИ](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=217308&page=962) див. задовольня́ти.
>
> ---
>
> [ЗАДОВОЛЬНЯ́ТИ](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=29071&page=962), рідко ЗАДОВІЛЬНЯ́ТИ, я́ю, я́єш, недок., ЗАДОВОЛЬНИ́ТИ, рідко ЗАДОВІЛЬНИ́ТИ, ню́, ни́ш, рідко ЗАДОВОЛИ́ТИ, лю́, ли́ш, док., кого, що. <…>

У літературі вживалися/вживаються обидва варіанти, але з *-о-* значно частіше:

- [задовольняти/задовольнити](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%5B%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D%D1%82%D0%B8%22%20%26%20lemma!=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D&showresults=1) — 61596 траплянь,
- [задовільняти/задовільнити](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%5B%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D%D1%82%D0%B8%22%20%26%20lemma!=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D&showresults=1) — 1948 траплянь.

Етимологічно варіант з *-і-* навіть «коректніший». Бо слово походить від праслов'янського [*voľa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/vo%C4%BEa) (через *-o-*; а праслов'янське *-o-* зазвичай переходить в українське *-і-* в закритому складі, наприклад **nosъ* → *ніс* (лишаючись *о* у відкритому — *носа*), праслов'янське *-ъ-* зазвичай переходить в українське *-о-*, наприклад **rъtъ* → *рот*). Але на практиці варіант з *-о-* «перемагає».

Приблизно така сама ситуація з варіантами [бог](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=4910&page=184) і [біг](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=4230&page=159) (у значенні «бог»): етимологічно *біг* коректніше, але *бог* нині вживають частіше (хоча *біг* теж зафіксоване в літературі/приказках).

Comment: Дякую і погоджуюсь, що обидва варіанти придатні до вжитку. Та прошу доопрацювати відповідь і розширити до меж запитання, щоб визнати її остаточно правильною. А майбутньому мати першоджерело з міцним обґрунтуванням для всіх випадків вжитку.

Comment: На першому етапі дослідження було виявлено, що чергування голосних (о - і) не відбувається. Натомість обидві словоформи існують в українській мові одночасно, як дві окремі лексичні одиниці. Отже, можемо припустити, що вони могли бути утворені від різних основ і можуть мати окремі семантичні ознаки, які залежатимуть від умов та способу вжитку.

Comment: 0



Більше за все через -і буде вживатися до неістот і властивим діловому та науковому стилям мовлення, в свою чергу через -о вживатися до істот і властивим літературному та публіцистичному стилям. Та це ще потрібно довести. Тут потрібен морфологічний і синтаксичний аналіз.

Comment: @Skill, Ви кажете «було виявлено, що чергування голосних (о - і) не відбувається», але у варіанті з -і- (на місці праслов'янського -o-) воно якраз відбувається: у закритому складі -і-, у відкритому складі -о- — наприклад: _ніс/носа_, _кіт/кота_, _задовільний/задоволення_. Але конкретно в дієсловах _{за/в/у}дов?льн{я/и}ти_ переміг «контретимологічний» варіант з -о- замість -і-.

Comment: @Skill, Ви кажете, що варіанти з -і- та -о- могли мати різне походження? І що на вибір -і- чи -о- може впливати семантика та стиль тексту? А чому Ви так вважаєте? Чи маєте якісь ідеї, як це можна спробувати довести чи спростувати? (Я, якщо чесно, не бачу підстав так вважати. І словник подає їх просто синонімами.)

Comment: на це піде деякий час, та думаю так. Дякуючи вашій відповіді, тепер стало можливим обгрунтувати та надати правильну відповідь на пов'язане запитання Yola.